# Vector line length vs. geographical distance (as a bird flies)

Tags: vector, line, distance, shortest-path, curvature

Is there a way to compare the length of a line (ESRI Shapefile in my case) to the actual distance it covers with freely available tools?

I am developing an optional path algorithm. The image below depicts a part of a river system. Some of the beds have obviously been straightened in the modern times. I would like to apply a coefficient to the straight parts for realistic prehistoric travel speed calculation.

Principally I am able to tell between large and small streams as they come from different datasets, so the large rivers having larger meanders (bottom right) is not much of an issue.

**UPDATE:** The original dataset has only straight polyline segments. Counting segments for a unit of distance could also do.

[image]

Comment: Using what GIS software?

Comment: This was done with QGIS but I would be happy to use any freely available software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry for the original question being somewhat too broad. The update is not right as well as the line segments include multiple vertices as I discovered later.

However, I wrote a small Python script that should solve the issue. Might be of use to somebody.

```
from shapefile import Reader
import math

fn = "E:/geogr/sample.shp"

sf = Reader(fn)
records = sf.shapeRecords()

with open("E:/geogr/out.txt", "w") as out_f:

    for rec in records:
        record = rec.record
        shape = rec.shape
        print("\n")
        print(len(shape.points))
        for i, p in enumerate(shape.points):

                p1 = None
                p2 = None
                bfd = 0
                d_sum = 0;
                n = 0
                while True:
                    n += 1
                    if (i<n-1) or (i+n) == len(shape.points):
                        break
                    for j, p1 in enumerate(shape.points[i-n:i+n+1]):
                        if j > 0:
                            d = math.hypot(p1[0] - p2[0], p1[1] - p2[1])
                            d_sum += d

                        p2 = p1
                    if d_sum >= 1000:
                        break

                if (p1 is not None) and (d_sum >= 1000):
                    bfd = math.hypot(shape.points[i-n][0] - p1[0], shape.points[i-n][1] - p1[1])
                    print(p[0], p[1], bfd/d_sum, sep=" ", file=out_f)
```

The result as viewed with CloudCompare:
[image]